# Catel nested UserControl: ViewModel instantiated multiple times (with Example)

Tags: catel

I have a Problem with Catel, ViewModels are instantiated multiple times.

This is a duplicate of my own question, but the old question is a big wall of text (which didnt help), and now I decided to rather include a demo-Project.

The demo-Project can be downloaded from here:
[Demo-Project (VS2013)](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F8DF0DE4DFA37CA6!111&authkey=!AEsjWFdw8itFIPg&ithint=file%2C7z)

Here is the Problem:

- Run Project,
- Open one Customer (double click or select then "Edit")
- Observe: the Nested Controls for the Orders: "OrderViewModelID" is 11...20 (actually you cannot see 16...20, forgot the scrollviewer)

  --> it should be "1...10" cause it's the first 10 ViewModel of type Order created.

  --> reason: OrderViewModel is instantiated MULTIPLE TIMES per Model
- Click on "New Shipper" (any order)
- "Cancel" the new Window
- Observe: the "OrderViewModelID" is now 21...30 (they were instantiated yet again!!!)

I put lots of time in this Problem already, and I just cannot find the reason.

Any help / insights?

Johannes Colmsee

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug. It has been fixed, see the [issue report](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-891) for the latest information.

btw. I really recommend that you use Catel.Fody, it will result in much cleaner view models.

Comment: Wow....ok, thanks. I will update my "old" question accordingly too, for our fellow developers. About Fody - we probably Need silverlight-compatibility, that is why I created my example accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I have to inform you, that the Bug is only fixed partly.

I will Highlight the steps which still are broken:

- Run Project,
- Open one Customer (double click or select then "Edit")
- Observe: the Nested Controls for the Orders: "OrderViewModelID" is 11...20 (actually you cannot see 16...20, forgot the scrollviewer)

  --> it should be "1...10" cause it's the first 10 ViewModel of type Order created.

  --> reason: OrderViewModel is instantiated MULTIPLE TIMES per Model

**- Click on "New Shipper" (any order)**

**- "Cancel" the new Window**

**- Observe: the "OrderViewModelID" is now 21...30 (they were instantiated yet again!!!)**

Update:

It was a bug in Catel 4.4 which has been fixed. Link to the [Catel Issue Tracker Item](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-893)

Comment: Then report in the official issue tracker please. StackOverflow is not the place to report bugs.